# How to reset visual studio settings to my saved settings with just a single shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was wondering how is it possible to assign keyboard shortcut that will reset my opened VS window to my saved settings (full setting import)?

I am not talking about Tools > Import and Export Setting (I want to have a single Reset shortcut) also I am not talking just about ResetWindowLayout option (this one only resets windows layout, not all settings).

Manually all settings can be restored from saved file by going to

1. Tools > Import and Export Setting
2. Import Selected Environment Settings > select "Just Import new settings, overwriting my current settings" radio button
3. Choose a collection of Setting to Import > select a saved file
4. Choose Setting to import > Check "All Setting" checkbox
5. Click Finish

Too many steps, I just want to import my setting with one click, similar to ResetWindowLayout to which I can assign a keyboard shortcut.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New Answer

Install the macro extension from Microsoft.
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b/view/Reviews

Create two macro files. Adjust your paths. (I think you need to keep the commented reference path.
**SaveSettings:**

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "-export:C:\\Docs\\VS2013\\Settings\\BACKUP.vssettings");
```

**LoadSettings:**

```
dte.ExecuteCommand('Tools.ImportandExportSettings', '-import:C:\\Docs\\VS2013\\Settings\\BACKUP.vssettings');
```

### Old Answer - Still can work for you. I unsure the project is not supported anymore.

Your are in luck. We both had this same question today and I was considering making something myself before stumbling on this.

[VS Settings Switcher](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa71b090-7a6d-49a3-98aa-54d5e3feaa6b)

This supports saving and loading settings as profile names.

Even better, you can set a solution to default to a particular settings profile. Useful if your project is a web project to appear as a certain layout. Or a class library project with unit testing layouts. Or even for switching between multi and single monitor.

One of the tests I performed with this tool was to not only close and move around my tool windows, but I deleted icons from my toolbars. I then restored all my changes by applying the saved profile.